# Ajax.ActionLink with multiple triggers

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I have a webpage with a large number of links that all need to call the same controller action using AJAX. Each link differs by only a single parameter. Right now I'm creating an Ajax.ActionLink for each one, but this produces very verbose HTML. How can I create a single ActionLink and trigger it from each of my links? I'm using MVC3 with C#

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused at this line :"How can I create a single ActionLink and trigger it from each of my links?"

Comment: Maybe that's the wrong approach but I want to avoid creating multiple ActionLinks. I thought maybe I could create a single one and "call" it from each of the multiple links. Perhaps there is a much simpler way though.

Comment: Also, I'm using jQuery so maybe I can bind a function to each of the links, and that function can "call" the ActionLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much answered your question.  You can bind a click function to the anchor and have that call a jquery.ajax method.  You could also create a standard anchor and have it call a method on the onClick event:

```
<a onclick="myFunc('thisLink');" href="#"/>
```

myFunc would then accept the parameter indicating which ajax function to call or pass a parameter to the ajax function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc(link) { //perform the ajax call } 
</script>
```

Comment: If he's using jQuery, there's no need for an in-line `onclick` handler. Use `$("selector").click(function() {...})` instead.

Comment: But how can I do this and take advantage of the MVC Ajax.ActionLink, which has an UpdateTargetId and LoadingElementId? With the simple jQuery functions I have to update the target and switch the animated gif display.

Comment: @Ajax.ActionLink("Click to load pieces", "History",
                 new { gameId = 1, move = 1 },
                 new AjaxOptions
                 {
                     UpdateTargetId = "pieces",
                     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                     HttpMethod = "GET",
                     LoadingElementId = "ajaxloader"
                 })

Comment: Looks like I was trying to use ActionLink for something it isn't designed for. I went with a single jQuery .load() function and bound calls to the individual links. Thanks all for the help.